# How to open windows application from Browser

Tags: javascript, html, windows

We have a weird requirement, that is User should be able to launch windows application from the browser.

Ex:- "Click Here" to send mail, when the user clicks on the link We will launch an Email application by "mailTo". But here we have a custom windows application by name "XYZ" desktop application.

Some people advised me to Use URI, But I failed to get it done.

Can someone provide me more inputs to achieve this, the solution should work in all the browsers and all the Operating systems(App will be installed in all OS like windows|linux|Mac).

Comment: Only Windows can run "windows application", why should this work in all operating systems ..?

Comment: You are right. I mean the application has to open in respective Operating system and it should be installed there

Comment: The standard way is to download a file, when user can select an application to open the file with.

Comment: Is there any other approach than this

Comment: Not really, for security reasons, browsers are not capable to access the local file system without user's interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is against all security measures browser developers apply. So if you find a solution it might still work on the old IE8 and some other outdated browsers. In modern browsers most users and especially companies use a "boxed" mode, which means that even with user interaction no application would run/can be started on the desktop OS.
With mobile its a little bit different. With trusted apps (distributed and checked by either google or apple) and getting the consent of the user and respecting system settings for privacy it works as of today (2020 04).
Options you have with boxed browsers:

- Run javascript in sandbox and than connect to databases, other sites aso
- Give an option for download (mostly disallowed/blocked) in company environment.

The email tag is an artefact from the good all days, where criminal elements where still robbing people with guns and not by email drive (send) by.

Comment: Many browsers still support [protocol handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers) to open email links from web pages.